# Google Chrome autofill not working on two page login websites

Tags: google-chrome

I have a password saved for a website (https://twilio.com)

There is no autofill on the username page (https://twilio.com/console/login):

[image]

However, there's autofill on the password page (https://twilio.com/console/login/password):

[image]

What can I do to make it autofill the username as well?

I've noticed that the saved password URL was `https://www.twilio.com/login/password`:

[image]

I have tried changing the url to `https://www.twilio.com/login` (by exporting and re-importing all passwords) to no avail.

I have also tried wiping out and reinstalling Google Chrome (including profile data).

Answer (score 0):

try this: press shift, ctrl and delete while using chrome and click clear data and then log out of chrome , restart the device and sign in again.